# How to remove the undefined object from array using angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
let myArr=[{
    "name": "",
    "columns": [
      {
        
        "data": "test1",
        "type": "",
        
        
      },
      undefined,
      {
        "data": "test1",
        "type": "",
      }
    ],
    "info": "value",
    
  }]
```

Above array of object having undefined or null values, I have to remove the undefined values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by combining [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (the core piece) as shown in the runnable code below:

```js
let myArr=[{
    "name": "",
    "columns": [
      {        
        "data": "test1",
        "type": "",        
      },
      undefined,
      {
        "data": "test1",
        "type": "",
      }
    ],
    "info": "value",    
  }]
  
myArr = myArr.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, key) => {
  let value = o[key];  
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = value.filter(o2 => o2);
  }
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myArr[0].columns = myArr[0].columns.filter((data)=>data!==undefined);
```

This will filter out all the undefined values inside of columns